# What's this JRPG Famicom game shopkeeper saying to me: ごようは　どちらです？

Tags: meaning

The scene is I'm a totally knightly dude trying to save the world and all that and I walk into a shop. The shopkeeper says to me: ここは　ぶきとぼうぐの みせです (This is the weapon & armor shop.) The game is old so no kanji in this one.

The next thing they say to me is: ごようは　どちらです？

Then I have 2 options I can pick:

> ものを　かう (buy thing)
> ものを　うる (sell thing)

I'm not certain what the ごようは　どちらです？ line means. My guess would be something like "Which do you desire?" I'm not sure though. The ご I think is just to be honorific and the よう is desire?

*Edit*
Thank you for the answer Jimmy. I marked this as answered. That sounds much more accurate than what I had. I'll add this to my study rotation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe ごよう in this context is 御用. It means "business" or "errand".

So「ごようは　どちらです」means "what is your business?" or more literally, "your business, which one is it?"